# ASP.NET Core custom authentication scheme, authorize attribute does not allow user to login

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to incorporate my custom authentication scheme, unfortunately after setting the USER.IDENTITY.IsAuthentication to true after successful bypass of my login function the AuthorizeFilter still reject my access to the app.

startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
});
IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
services.AddSingleton(mapper);
services.AddDbContext<AwmDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));           

services.AddScoped<IUsersLogic, UsersLogic>();
services.AddScoped<IUsersRepo, Repo.UsersRepo>();

services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = "FiverSecurityScheme";
    options.DefaultScheme = "FiverSecurityScheme";
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "FiverSecurityScheme";
})
  .AddCookie("FiverSecurityScheme", options =>
  {
      options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Users/Login");
      options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Users/Login");
  });
services.AddAuthorization();
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

startup-config services

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areas",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
    }
```

login code

```
    public async Task<bool> LoginUser(LoginViewModel login, HttpContext context
    )
    {
        var userFound = await _usersRepo.LoginUser(login.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket;
        if (IsPasswordMatch(login.UserPassword, userFound.Salt.TrimEnd(), userFound.Password.TrimEnd()))
        {
            // create claims  
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
  {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, login.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "mihail@abv.bg")
  };

            // create identity  
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "FiverSecurityScheme");

            // create principal  
            //ClaimsPrincipal principal = new    ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { identity });
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            context.User = principal;
            // sign-in  
            await context.SignInAsync("FiverSecurityScheme", principal);
            return (true);
        }         
        else
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, [we can't accept images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Hi Dave, I posted the code and sorry that I previously did not.